# java.lang.Object over a MULE SOAP Component

Tags: soap, mule, esb, mule-studio

I need to pass to soap component an object of a known class which is composed from two strings.
the soap request should be like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsd="http://wsTest/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsd:find>
         <entity>
            <id>string_1</id>
            <type>string_2</type>
         </entity>
      </wsd:find>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a suitable MULE transformer where I can  input the two Strings then convert them to the wanted class object ??
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use an expression transformer:

```
<expression-transformer expression="#[new com.mycomp.Entity('string_1','string_2')]" />
```

assuming the `com.mycomp.Entity` class has a two string constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the two arguments are coming from an http post request like that http://localhost:8088/?string_1=xxxx&string_2=yyyy, how can I replace them dynamically in the MEL ??

thank you .